# How to manually update/generate correlator value with DFP

Tags: google-dfp

Trying to figure out how to generate a new correlator value for DFP without a whole page refresh or calling refresh() on all the ads on the page. There is a certain section of the site, that has certain sections of the page refresh via AJAX rather than completely reloading the page, but we would like to at these points, start using a new correlator value.

If there were a magic function like googletag.pubads().newCorrelator() that would be amazing, but I have not found anything.

I have tried the refresh() call which DOES generate a new correlator, but also refreshes all the ads on the page, which is not what I am looking to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This has been added to the GPT API recently.

You should be able to update correlator values with `googletag.pubads().updateCorrelator();`

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_updateCorrelator

Release notes: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/179039?hl=en